# This.state property is considered "undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm fetching data from my backend to my frontend. After I invoke 
`let data = response.json()`, I then invoke `const bartData = Object.entries(data)`. So, I'm creating an array that holds the key/value pairs of my original object. I then set the state of my component `this.setState({allStations: bartData})`, where the property `allStations: []`. This is where the problem comes up- I want visual confirmation that I'm geting the right data and manipulate it the way I want to so I invoke `console.log(this.state.allStations[0])` and it gives me the correct contents but when I go further `console.log(this.state.allStations[0][0]`, I get an error that states

> this.state.allStations[0] is undefined

Why? 
Also, I get that I'm putting an array inside of an array, which is why I was surprised that `console.log(this.state.allStations[0])`gave me the contents of the original array. **Picture of console.log(this.state.allStations)** [this.state.allStations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Qblf.jpg)

```
constructor(){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       allStations: []
    }
}

 async getAllStations(){
        try{
            const response = await fetch(`/base-station-routes`);
            let data = await response.json();     

            // console.log(response);
            // let test = JSON.parse(bartData);
            // console.log(test)

            const bartData = Object.entries(data);

            // console.log(bartData[0][0]) works
            this.setState({
                allStations: bartData
            })
        }catch(e){
            console.log(`Error: ${e}`)
        }

}

render(){
    console.log(this.state.allStations[0]);
    return( more stuff )
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQFeo.png
```

Comment: I think you set the state incorrectly, try `this.setState({allStations: [ bartData ] })` instead

Comment: @Yeysides I fixed it. The error still shows up

Answer (score 1):

In render function before `console.log(this.state.allStations[0])` you should check the state value.
Render function executes before fetching data from backend, my suggestion to do this

```
if(this.state.allStations) && console.log(this.state.allStations[0])
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks for commenting. Check my edit, I'm posting a picture of this.state.allStations

Answer (score 0):

Do a conditional render to prevent it from showing the array before response has been sent.

Add something like:

```
constructor(){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       isLoading: true,
       allStations: []
    }
}
```

You need to use React Lifecycles and stick Fetch inside:

```
componentWillMount(){
    fetch('/base-station-routes') // Already Async
    .then(res => res.json()) // Convert response to JSON
    .then(res => this.setState({ isLoading: false, allStations: res})) // you can call it bartData, but I like to stick with res
    .catch(err => { //.catch() handles errors
        console.error(err) 
    })
}
```

and then in your Render:

```
render(){
    return( 
          <div>
              {this.state.isLoading ? <span>Still Loading</span> : // do a map here over your data}
          </div>
    )
}
```

This prevents doing anything with the data before your response is there.

Comment: Thanks this really helped. However, I have another question- on my initial render, allStations = [], but when I call setState it should trigger a rerender. Why didn't my state change? Why was it still considered undefined?

Comment: @hello_there - fetch is already Async so you can just do it with fetch(`/base-station-routes`).then(res => res.json()).then(res => this.setState(//do stuff)).catch(//handle errors). I edited mine to show you the proper way.